# Extract domain from URL in python

Tags: python, url

I have an url like:
`http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/`

I want to get:
`hostname.com`

What module can I use to accomplish this?
I want to use the same module and method in python2.

Comment: I would imaging you could use regex.

Comment: You can just use str.split(), it's easy

Comment: url.split('/')[2] will give you 'abc.hostname.com' you can extract it using split or re any method.

Comment: maybe a duplicate, but better answers here

Answer (score 139):

For parsing the domain of a URL in Python 3, you can use:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

domain = urlparse('http://www.example.test/foo/bar').netloc
print(domain) # --> www.example.test
```

However, for reliably parsing the top-level domain (`example.test` in this example), you need to install a specialized library (e.g., [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/)).

Answer (score 75):

Instead of regex or hand-written solutions, you can use python's [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

print(urlparse('http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/'))
>> ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='abc.hostname.com', path='/somethings/anything/', params='', query='', fragment='')

print(urlparse('http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/').netloc)
>> abc.hostname.com
```

To get without the subdomain

```
t = urlparse('http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/').netloc
print ('.'.join(t.split('.')[-2:]))
>> hostname.com
```

Comment: In Python3 the lib `urlparse` was renamed to `urllib.parse`.

Comment: will it work with something like test.mytest.example.com ?

Comment: @qasimzee it won't, it's getting everything from the first `.` onward

Comment: It will fail with `*.co.uk` or `*.ac.uk` domains.

Comment: @mommi84 You'll need to prepend `http://`

Comment: `t.split('.')[-2:]` literally keeps only the last two substrings, so I am afraid it will just return `co.uk` and `ac.uk`, whether you prepend that or not.

Comment: This (wrong due to the mentioned reasons) answer has so many up-votes and then we wonder why different software and websites have so many bugs...

Answer (score 34):

You can use [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract).

Example code:

```
from tldextract import extract
tsd, td, tsu = extract("http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/") # prints abc, hostname, com
url = td + '.' + tsu # will prints as hostname.com    
print(url)
```

Comment: `tldextract` is not a standard lib ( at least not in python 2.7 ) , I think you should mention that. Still +1

Comment: Works well! But, getting No handlers could be found for logger "tldextract", how to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have it in an accessible string, and assuming we want to be generic for having multiple levels on the top domain, you could:

```
token=my_string.split('http://')[1].split('/')[0]
top_level=token.split('.')[-2]+'.'+token.split('.')[-1]
```

We split first by the `http://` to remove that from the string. Then we split by the `/` to remove all directory or sub-directory parts of the string, and then the `[-2]` means we take the second last token after a `.`, and append it with the last token, to give us the top level domain.

There are probably more graceful and robust ways to do this, for example if your website is `http://.com` it will break, but its a start :)

Comment: your code can be simplified more    token=my_string.split('/')[2] though it will also work for ftp:// and https:// also.

Comment: That is valid feedback :)

Answer (score -5):

Try:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse('http://abc.hostname.com/somethings/anything/')
domain = parsed.netloc.split(".")[-2:]
host = ".".join(domain)
print host  # will prints hostname.com
```

Comment: won't work with .co.uk