# i am new on python, I work on a fake news detection algorithm, I have a problem extracting the name of the site from url

Tags: python

```
text = 'https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/09/us/politics/corkers-blast-at-trump-has-other-republicans-nodding-in-agreement.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fpolitics\r\n'

test = re.findall(r"^http* com$",text)
```

result i have :

```
test = [ ]
```

The output I am expecting would be like this:

```
www.nytimes.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't use the question title for your question description; put that in the description section. Your question title should be a summary of your problem (ideally) stated as a question (refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples and details). Also be sure to include all relevant question tags; as your question is about a non-matching regular expression; including the `regex` tag would have been a good choice to categorize your question further.

Comment: If you need a more reliable way to split URL to parts it is better to use `urllib.parse` module instead of regular expressions. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476496/6682517).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern is wrong. There shouldn't be any space in the pattern, replace `*` by `.*` and avoid anchoring your regex with a `$` in the end. Try this

```
>>> re.findall(r"^http.*?com", text)
['https://www.nytimes.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
test = re.findall(r"www.+com",text)
```

Output :

```
['www.nytimes.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match http or https and also any type of domain (.gov.us, .com.de, .edu...)

```
test = re.findall(r"^http.*\:\/\/(.*?)\/",text)
```

^http = Begning with http

`"^http.*` = will match for http or https

`\:\/\/` = escape ://

`(.*?)` = match group a.k.a what you want (without the `?` will match until the last  `/`)

`\/` = first ocurrence of "/"

Comment: thanks for your answers