# How to get host name from website using python

Tags: python

I would like to look get the host name using requests repository in python. I tried to do this like that:

```
pprint(requests.get("https://www.facebook.com/").headers['domain'])
```

but it doesn't work. If it is possible in other repository I would be grateful for any answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113335/extract-domain-from-url-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Regular Expression - Extract subdomain & domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703360/regular-expression-extract-subdomain-domain)

```py
import requests
import re

p = re.compile("^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)")

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
domain = p.match(r.url).group(1)
print(domain)
```