# How can I remove 'www.' from original URL through [urllib] parse in python?

Tags: python, parsing, url, urllib

Original URL ▶ https://www.exeam.org/index.html

I want to extract **exeam.org/** or **exeam.org** from original URL.

To do this, I used `urllib` the most powerful parser in Python that I know,
but unfortunately `urllib` (`url.scheme`, `url.netloc` ...) couldn't give me the type of format I wanted.

Comment: `'.'.join(urlparse('https://www.exeam.org/index.html').netloc.split('.')[1:])` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113335/extract-domain-from-url-in-python

Comment: what do you mean by `not only the original URL of the Inquiry but also the majority`? I am sorry not to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to extract the domain name from a url using `urllib):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
surl = "https://www.exam.org/index.html"
urlparsed = urlparse(surl)
# network location from parsed url
print(urlparsed.netloc)
# ParseResult Object
print(urlparsed)
```

this will give you `www.exam.org`, but you want to further decompose this to registered domain if you are after just the `exam.org` part. so besides doing simple splits, which could be sufficient, you could also use library such as `tldextract` which knows how to parse subdmains, suffixes and more:

```
from  tldextract import extract

ext = extract(surl)
print(ext.registered_domain)
```

this will produce:

```
exam.org
```