# How to extract a substring from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'yahoo.co.in']

Output = ['.com', '.in']
```

How do I get this output without using regular expressions?

Tried using nested for loop and partition function but could not get the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract domain from URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113335/extract-domain-from-url-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
output = set(f".{w.split('.')[-1]}" for w in a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
set(["."+ x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for x in a])
```

Or using `pop()`

```
set(["."+ x.rsplit('.', 1).pop() for x in a]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using nested for loop. Try this:

```
a = ['google.com','bing.com','yahoo.co.in']
output = []
for ele in a:
    count = 0
    for char in reversed(ele):
        count += 1
        if char == '.':
            break
        
    word = ele[-1*count:]
    if word not in output:
        output.append(word) 

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
a = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'yahoo.co.in']
output = []
for domain in a:
    suffix = '.' + str(domain.split('.')[-1])
    if not suffix in output:
        output.append(suffix)
```