# extracting URL/TLD from link using tldextract library python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tld

I'm trying to extract the URLs from few links using `tldextract`. Since my links are in different format can anybody help me to extract the URL.

```
import tldextract

ext = tldextract.extract('booking.com__booking.com_content_privacy.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLUBiAEBmAExuAEHyAEP2AEB6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuALVsdeSBsACAdICJDBkZWExNDc4LWZ')
```

so in above example, I want to extract `booking.com` but it doesn't give desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need provide right input. `booking.com__booking.com_content_privacy.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLUBiAEBmAExuAEHyAEP2AEB6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuALVsdeSBsACAdICJDBkZWExNDc4LWZ` is NOT valid URL. Here is example you need:

```
In [35]: tldextract.extract('https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/sunny.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAQoggJCI3NlYXJjaF9wYXJpcywgaWxlIGRlIGZyYW5jZSwgZnJhbmNlSAlYBGhsiAEBmAEJuAEZyAEM2AEB6AEB-AEDiAIBqAIDuALp
    ...: hrCkBsACAdICJDg3YTU5MjQzLTA1NWYtNDc3NS1hZTBhLTcyNDhjZDZmN2EzNtgCBeACAQ&sid=60f41096ef20067ac373b5ad3474226b&all_sr_blocks=29237402_92229029_2_2_0;checkin=2023-07-22;checkout=2023-07-29;dist=0;group_adul
    ...: ts=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=29237402_92229029_2_2_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=29237402_92229029_2_2_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=
    ...: popularity;sr_pri_blocks=29237402_92229029_2_2_0__95486;srepoch=1686897515;srpvid=87832eb4b6ed00f2;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl')
Out[35]: ExtractResult(subdomain='www', domain='booking', suffix='com')
```

More examples and usage here: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract
Probably, `tldextract` isn't the right lib for you. You need to process those  urls and process. May be, replace `__` with `/` . It's more of data cleaning task and is very specific to your input data. This might help [Extract domain from URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113335/extract-domain-from-url-in-python)