# Extracting Webpage Title in Safe Format for File Naming

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

Using Python I'd like to scrape some information from a webpage and save the info to a .txt file named using the title of the page scraped.

Unfortunately many pages contain special characters that can't be used in file names, so ideally I want to extract the title you would get if you did file/save from a browser.

Is it possible to achieve this with BeautifulSoup or Selenium?

I can get the page title with soup, and then clean it, but if there is a more efficient way of getting the browser-cleaned title I'd love to know how.

EDIT:

So far I have achieved a workable result with the following code. I used YouTube as an example but really would prefer an all-purpose page-title retrieval in browser save format if possible. Probably doesn't exist, but there's always hope.

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvCBzhhydNk")

title = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', br.title().replace("YouTube", "")).strip()

print(title)
```

Comment: Selenium does not have that feature, you have to get the title, then write simple logic to avoid the special characters or change the special characters to something else.

Comment: Having an example website and target would be very useful.

Comment: ...you could use something like [uipath](https://dev.tutorialspoint.com/uipath/uipath_studio_recording.htm#) to have it nearly save a page and get the name, but that would be an insanely convoluted and inefficient process just to get a name

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't know of any *"all-purpose page-title retrieval in browser save format"*, but what you're doing so far is not too bad (though I particularly prefer the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295152/12652373) and its comments from [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498405/hardmooth)hardmooth and [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627278/alex-krycek)AlexKrycek).

You can always save it as a little function if you'll be needing it often and use something like [urlparse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476496/12652373) or [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/) to get the domain if you'll be using sites other than YouTube as well.

So something like:

```
# import tldextract

def cleanPageTitle(origTitle, pageUrl):
    domain = tldextract.extract(pageUrl).domain
    cleaned = "".join([
            x for x in origTitle if (x.isalnum() or x in "._- ")
        ]).replace(domain, "")
    return cleaned
```

so that you can just call as

```
title = cleanPageTitle(br.title(), "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvCBzhhydNk")
```

Comment: I like the look of 'isalnum', never seen that before, very nice!

Comment: @pglove That's exactly what the first thought I had when I came across that answer =)